# read an txt file incorrectly use the separator

Tags: python, csv

In the python Jupiter notebook, I used `read_csv(data_set, sep='|', encoding='ISO-8859-1')` to read a txt file with '|' as a separator. However, several rows are not correctly split.

one row as an example is:

DC|discontinue|"DC|167|169|IMPRESSION|Occurred

I got:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 | col_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC | discontinue | DC|167|169|IMPRESSION|Occurred |  |  |  |  |

I expect:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 | col_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC | discontinue | DC | 167 | 169 | IMPRESSION | Occurred |

I think the quotation mark causes this mistake, but I don't know how to fix this. Are there any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: What is the difference between the actual and expected outputs?

Comment: It shows two tables incorrectly, I have revised it. Thank you.

Comment: What about the quotation mark before the DC?

Comment: Before the second 'DC', there is a quotation mark after the '|', I am thinking that causes the separator not to work, but I am not sure. Moreover, I don't know how to fix it inside the `read_csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the problem:

The program is not ignoring the double quote as you expected, instead it's appending a (supposed) missing double quote at the end to prevent syntax error, which results in the entire input after the double quote being counted as a single string.

One possible way this can work is by using RegEx inside the **sep** parameter of the **read_csv method**, so your code should look something like this :

```
read_csv(data_set, sep='[|]', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

The '[ , ]' in RegEx implies matching any non-whitespace character separated by a ' , ' (at least for python it does), so it ignores any other characters to be used as separators for the method, which works for your case.

The only problem with this method is that the double quotes are included along with DC as the input, so input actually becomes : **"DC**

If you want to deal with this completely, the best method that I can think of is to parse the entire datafile in python and remove all instances of **"**.
This could easily be done by importing the .txt file as a string and then using the methods specified [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-deleting-all-occurrences-of-character/) to remove all double quotes from the file.

Comment: Thank you for the help, your code works! It really helps.

Comment: That's great !! Could you please accept my answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) if it's the correct one

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to specify a different quote character in the [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) function (that isn't present in the file). Pandas would then ignore the quote character and process the field correctly. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter='|', quotechar="\0")
df['col_3'] = df['col_3'].str.replace('"', '')  # remove quotes

print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
  col_1        col_2 col_3  col_4  col_5       col_6     col_7
0    DC  discontinue    DC    167    169  IMPRESSION  Occurred
```

Alternatively, instead of changing the `quotechar` parameter you could use `quoting=3` (i.e. `csv.QUOTE_NONE`)

---

Taken from the `read_csv()` docs:

**quotechar** str (length 1), optional

The character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter and it will be ignored.

**quoting** int or `csv.QUOTE_*` instance, default 0

Control field quoting behavior per csv.QUOTE_* constants. Use one of QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could I know what "\0" and 3 represent?

Comment: `\0` is Python escape notation for a null character, which would not be present in your file. Any character not present in the file woukd work. The 3 tells `read_csv()` that no quoting is present

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Since minotman answered first and that works, I will accept that. But your code also works and thanks a lot!